# How to get the arrayList inside documents in firebase firestore in ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to ios please consider..I have collection as **organisationStandardTemplate** below is screenshot is add...I want to store my array list from `**roles** array list` present inside the documents.

[image]

> This is android code its working fine same as I want in iOS using
>   swift language..

```
   FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("organisationStandardTemplate")
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    if (task.getResult() != null) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                try {
                                orgTemplate = (ArrayList<HashMap>) documentSnapshot.get("roles");
                                } catch (Exception e){
                                Log.e("Excep", e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

> **IOS Code**

```
  func organisationStandardTemplate(){

  var orgTemplate = [AnyObject]() // here i crated my array list

  let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("organisationStandardTemplate").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil{
                // print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }else {

              orgTemplate = //How to get and store into my orgTemplate array list 
                }
            }
        }

  }
```

**Document**
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

> **Note:** I have only one document but I do not want to get based on
>   DocumentID becase I have two database like testing and production so
>   every time  I cannot change inside code..

Answer (score 0):

Declare Arraylist

```
var orgTemplate = [AnyObject]()
```

---

```
 for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

          self.orgTemplate =  (document.data()["roles"] as  AnyObject) as! [AnyObject]
          print("resultdefault =sizess     :   \(self.orgTemplate.count)")
          print("resultdefault =orginaldatas     :   \(self.orgTemplate)")
    }
```